# My application is not present in the AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to get into a dev. Android.

For that I use Android Studio.

I can not see my app in the AVD. It starts well but my application is not there.

In my logcat just error : ***Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?***

In advance thank you

Comment: need to restart the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the  android studio 0.3.4

has the problem that it takes a long time to crank or start the emulator.

**Solution by now:**

one way  is to use the AVD Manager to start the emulator first, and then Run the app, Selecting the already-running emulator.